# recyclerview save state in Activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-recyclerview, lifecycle

What would be the best way to save state without sharedpreferences? In my simple app, It is possible to create several recyclerview, but everytime I change the activity and return or rotate screen, they are all gone. I am doing both recycling view and the life-cycle of activity, but it is pretty difficult to understand for me.

Again, the point is What would be the best way to save state without sharedpreferences?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is Viewmodels

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.